# How to get the content inside string in python

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion

I have string variable in python as

```
variable = "[['Acc',{'b':1,'s':1}],['ABC',{'c':1,'d':1}]]"
```

the type of this varible is `<class 'str'>`

I want output as 
`result = [['Acc',{'b':1,'s':1}],['ABC'],{'c':1,'d':1}]` 
which should be of type `<class 'list'>`

I dont know how to get this. Plz help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) - Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None, bytes and sets.

```
import ast

variable = "[['Acc',{'b':1,'s':1}],['ABC'],{'c':1,'d':1}]"
list1 = ast.literal_eval(variable)

print(list1)
print(type(list1))
```

O/P:

```
[['Acc', {'b': 1, 's': 1}], ['ABC'], {'c': 1, 'd': 1}]
<class 'list'>
```